# Reference request for an early theorem of Gromov

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In his talk [Misha Gromov- How does he do it](http://www.slideshare.net/simonsfoundation/mikhail-gromov-how-does-he-do-it), Jeff Cheeger mentions a theorem of Gromov proved sometime in the early 70's. Theorem: *Every manifold admitting a sequence of metrics such that the diameter and curvature go to zero is finitely covered by a nilmanifold.*
Further, he says that the proof is not easy even today; something usually associated with Gromov! 
It would be great to read the original paper, and even better if some book contains it. Please help me find them. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to add Ruh's extension to Gromov's paper "Almost flat manifolds" J. Differential Geom. 17 (1982), no. 1, 1–14.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

M. Gromov, Almost flat manifolds, J. Differential Geometry 13 (1978) 231-241

online at http://seven.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/3[20].pdf

Answer (score 7):

The book "Gromov's almost flat manifolds" by Buser and Karcher is a nice exposition of Gromov's result.